# Combining two list of pairs

Tags: c++

I have in my hpp.file this constructor;

```
Collection(Collection collection, Collection collection2);
```

which initializes the collection to contain all the contains from the two parameters;

Information is stored in list of pairs like:

```
std::list<std::pair<std::string, size_t>> info_;
```

And now I am trying to merge these two in cpp.file but dont know how. I have tried to iterate both collection and add informations of both to new collection, but it wont work:

```
Collection::Collection(Collection collection, Collection collection2){

  Collection merged;
  std::list<std::pair<std::string, size_t>> ::const_iterator it;  
  for (it = collection.info_.begin(); it != collection.info_.end(); it++) {
        merged.collection.push_back(std::pair<std::string, size_t>(it->first, it->second));

        }

 }
```

Do you guys have any tips?

Comment: How is `Collection` implemented? What does "it wont work" mean? Do you have any error messages?

Comment: In you example you add only collection, but you don't do anything with collection 2

Comment: I guess, in your constructor, you do not want to add the pairs to `merged`, but to the object you are initializing (`this`)

Comment: Depending on what you mean by merged and how duplicates should be handled, `merged.collection.insert(merged.collection.end(), collection.begin(), collection.end()); merged.collection.insert(merged.collection.end(), collection2.begin(), collection2.end());` maybe?

Comment: Thanks eike and Shawn. So I had to add pairs to the object I was initializing, not the merged. And the inserts worked well.